# How to prepare Windows based environment to test multiple PHP versions?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, iis

I guess this is more general question so asking it at superuser, not on stack exchange.

I have to create windows environment with both IIS and Apache, and test latest 3 PHP versions. (At the moment those are 5.4.42, 5.5.25 and 5.6.10.).

I used to develop PHP in versions 3 and 4, but never actually needed to run tests of the same code on 3 different versions.

I had a great Idea to try to find 3 versions of Xampp / Wamp, but it's not really available. There are 5.5.24 and 5.6.8 versions.

What would be the best approach for this situation?

Comment: I'd try to create a copy of 5.5.24-based XAMPP and replace its PHP with 5.4.x. Just remember to keep `php.ini`.

Comment: [Apache, MySQL, PHP server on Windows with multiple, simultaneous PHP versions](http://www.dionysopoulos.me/amp-server-on-win-with-multiple-php-versions/)